# Must a Bean have a default constructor?

Tags: java, javabeans

I'm reading the [JavaBean specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) but I can't find a sentence where it clearly states that a bean must have a default constructor. So does it or doesn't?

Comment: Some API's, such as JPA, or JAXB, will expect it, but it is not a strict requirement.

Comment: It doesn’t have to.  For one thing, bean frameworks are supposed to recognize a constructor annotated with [@ConstructorProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html).

Comment: better title must been "why bean have no-arg constructor"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look at the wikipedia about java bean:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

The bean should have a public default constructor is one of the rules for it qualifying as a JavaBean. However, this is not explicitly defined by the standard, but is a good practice adopted by many frameworks.

**EDIT:** If we were to elaborate about the reasons WHY a non-args constructor is desired (but generally not enforced), below is one of the reasons:

CDI frameworks generally have two way of injecting dependencies in your bean:

**Constructor injection:** Where you have defined explicitly the dependencies of your bean in its constructor. Example (Spring):

```
@Component
public class SuchBean {
     private MuchDependency muchDependency;

     @Autowired
     public SuchBean(MuchDependency muchDependency){
         this.muchDependency = muchDependency;
     }

}
```

**Setter/Reflection injection**: Where you haven't necessarily injected any dependencies through the constructor, but the dependencies are injected by the CDI environment by either using reflection or the setters. Example:

```
@Component
public class SuchBean {
     // this dep doesn't have a setter, so the CDI will use reflection to set it
     @Autowired private MuchDependencyWithReflection muchDependencyWithReflection;
     // this dep has a setter so the CDI will use the setter to set it
     @Autowired private MuchDependencyWithSetter muchDependencyWithSetter;

     public void setMuchDependencyWithSetter(MuchDependencyWithSetter muchDependencyWithSetter){
         this.muchDependencyWithSetter = muchDependencyWithSetter;
     }
}
```

In the above example, if you haven't explicitly defined the no-args constructor, of course, you know, Java provides it for you (cause every class that doesn't have any constructor explicitly defined, just has an automatically provided no-args constructor). So everything would be fine and dandy until you decide to define your own constructor with args:

```
@Component
public class SuchBean {
     // this dep doesn't have a setter, so the CDI will use reflection to set it
     @Autowired private MuchDependencyWithReflection muchDependencyWithReflection;
     // this dep has a setter so the CDI will use the setter to set it
     @Autowired private MuchDependencyWithSetter muchDependencyWithSetter;

     public SuchBean(String nonDefaultConstuctorArg){
         System.out.println(nonDefaultConstuctorArg);
     }

     public void setMuchDependencyWithSetter(MuchDependencyWithSetter muchDependencyWithSetter){
         this.muchDependencyWithSetter = muchDependencyWithSetter;
     }
}
```

In the above example it is not obvious, but any dependency framework would complain and won't be able to instantiate it, because in fact, when you are using reflection/setter injection, the framework does:

```
Constructor.newInstance();
```

behind the scenes AND then injects the dependencies. However, since you just made your class not have a default constructor, newInstance() without args wouldn't work. Hence, you need a default args constructor in this case. To summarize:

- If you use constructor injection, you don't need a no-args constructor.
- If you use reflection/setter injection, you need to use a no-args
  constructor.
- Since good code should have good conventions, the JavaBeans standard
  "nudges" you into having a default no-args constructor everywhere to have a consistent, conventional code that is usable across various frameworks and being readable/understandable/maintainable due to its standardization.

Comment: does wikipedia provide a source or link for that rule?

Comment: @wero don't think so :)

Answer (score 3):

A bean does not need to have a default constructor. Simply because the spec does not define that requirement.

Additionally chapter *10.3 Instantiating a bean* talks about obtaining bean instances:

> A bean can be delivered as either a serialized template (which must be
>   deserialized to create an instance of the bean) or as an
>   implementation class (where a bean instance is created simply by
>   creating an instance of the class).

This strategy is implemented by `Beans.instantiate`: It looks for a serialized bean (a special named Java resource). If it doesn't find one it tries to instantiate the bean via `Class.newInstance`. But this mechanism clearly shows that the spec writers thought about providing a generic method to get bean instances which do not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need it (some refection framework required), but is a good practice